# How to avoid regcomp error 13 with this regular expression?

Tags: c, regex

I would like to use regular expression from here but a little bit differently :

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-B

I am trying  it like this:

```
ret = regcomp(preg,"^(?!01418710[0-9]{2}).*", REG_EXTENDED);
if (ret) {
    char errmsg[256];
    regerror(ret, preg, errmsg, sizeof(errmsg));
    printf("Error msg :%s (ret = %d) for regex:%s\n",errmsg,ret, prefix);
   return -1;
}
```

this is my regex: `^(?!01418710[0-9]{2}).*`

But I am stuck with return value of `regcomp`:

```
REG_BADRPT
```

According to man it means:

> Invalid use of repetition operators such as using '*' as the first character.

I currently can avoid this error with `^(\?!01418710[0-9]{2}).*` but the regular expression is different.

Similar meaning at this man:

> ?, * or + is not preceded by valid regular expression

How am I supposed to avoid this error ? Is my regex correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<regex.h>` POSIX regex does not support lookarounds.

You may match the simple pattern you have in the lookahead as a consuming pattern and if the `ret` is `REG_NOMATCH`, consider the match valid:

```
regex_t preg;
int ret;
ret = regcomp(&preg,"01418710[0-9]{2}", REG_EXTENDED);
... 
ret = regexec(&preg, "your_string", 0, NULL, 0);
if (ret == REG_NOMATCH) {
    printf("Matched!!!");
}
```

Comment: I m sorry i little bit change my regex. How to support lookarounds ?

Comment: With another regex library: PCRE, PCRE2, Boost, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers